# Take the wind out of someone's sails

Tags: grammar

"Take the wind out of someone's sails" means
"to cause someone to lose confidence or energy". How come it's "sails" and not "sail" in this case? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form with the singular is [a variant](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-the-wind-out-of-someones-sail).  The reason why the plural is more common is simple. Most boats have more than one sail.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations!